# Is this a division by modulo or what?

Tags: terminology

What is the name for this operation? Is it division by modulo? I'm really confused.

```
Here results will be always from 0 to 7, whichever dividend is.
-1 % 8 = 7
-7 % 8 = 1
-8 % 8 = 0
```

If previous operation is a division by modulo, so how I should name this operation?

```
Here results will be from -7 to 7.
-1 % 8 = -1
-7 % 8 = -7
-8 % 8 = 0
```

I'm totally noob in math.

I'm asking this question, because, for example, in `Python` programming language `% operator` will work as in first example I've given. In `C` / `C++` / `C#` `% operator` will work as in seconds example. This enraged me, when I was debugging my program; I've thought `% operator` in `C` will work exactly the same as in `Python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two languages compute slightly different things with the $\%$ operator.

**Python** computes the [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of the given two numbers. This means that the output will **always** lie in the range$[0,n)$ where $n$ is the modulus.

**C** computes the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) of the given two numbers after division. This tends to produce identical outputs as the modulo operator for positive inputs, but remainders can be negative when the number being divided is negative.

This is why you see a difference.

Comment: So the `mod` operation name is `division by modulo`? And other -- `division with remainder`? I'm asking about terminology. I'm noob in math and English language ;d

Comment: @GlebWernher the one Python uses is the `modulo` operator, and C uses the `remainder` operator.

Comment: I mean a mathematical names of this operation's.

Comment: That's exactly it...

Comment: You mean `division by modulo` & `division with remainder`? Sorry for stupid question ;d

Comment: No, just the modulus and remainder operators.

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same operation, namely reduce modulo 8,  as $-1$ is equivalent to $7$, etc. However C++ does not return the standard representatives you may be used to when the given number is negative.